# Why does my page work in IE9's IE7 mode, but not in IE7 itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I recently went live with our new home page, after heavily testing it in each of IE9's browser and document modes (*not* just compatibility mode, but actual IE7 and IE8 emulation). The site works in each mode, not to mention modern browsers. However, after it launched I got an email that said the site was very broken in IE7. I went to an abandoned machine and booted up Windows XP, started IE7, and loaded the page. To my horror, the layout was indeed broken! (NOT just the slideshow!)

**Most importantly, why does [my page](http://www.semo.edu/new_home.htm) not work in IE7, even though it works in IE7 mode in IE9?** And as a secondary question, what might be "wrong" with it?

**Edit**: I *have* figured out that one of my problems may be the slideshow, but adding `.ie7 #slideshow {display:none !important}` won't even hide the slideshow. I can't access it via CSS.

**Edit 2**: There is *another* problem that only shows up in native IE7 -- the footer on that home page, and [this page](http://www.semo.edu/building/), is ultra-tiny text that can't be zoomed. It doesn't do this in IE9's IE7 mode (not compatibility), or in any other browser. Another example of the discrepancy.

Comment: That is a bang-your-head-against-the-wall problem.

Comment: I just tried from IE8 using IE7 compatibility mode and site looks about the same.  A few things are slow to render at end of page load.  Can you provide a screenshot of what the real IE7 looks like and/or describe the problem?

Comment: Screenshots: http://kerrick.imgur.com/ie7_issues

Comment: Because it is Internet Explorer!  I mean, come on, what kind of browser returns true for the expression: '\v'=='v'?  Fortunately, IE7 is well on its way out.  Check the latest usage stats here: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: @Jonathan w3schools? naaahhh they have been proven unreliable source.

Comment: @Jonathan Not only do I distrust w3schools, but our site has 14% of its visits from IE7 still.

Luckily, most of those are from on-campus faculty computers, and Web Design & Support is trying to convince IT to upgrade them so we can just stop supporting it like we did for IE6.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't know about IE9's IE7-compatibility mode but the IE7-compatiblity mode built into IE8 is well known for not being a perfect copy of a real IE7. It has a large number of bugs and quirks of its own which do not appear in normal IE7.

It was bad enough that I would never have recommended anyone to actually use compatibility mode to test their site... except that you still need to cope with the occasional user who is actually using compatiblity mode on their live browser. So rather than making things easier for the developer, MS actually made things harder for us by adding yet another possible rendering engine to the mix which. Sigh.

I haven't tried IE9's compatibility modes, but if your experience is anything to go by, then they've still got the same problem. It's a shame (but not surprising) that MS didn't learn from the first time they made that blunder.

Rather than using compatibility modes to test, the best solution I know of is to use an application called [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), which allows you to install and run all versions of IE alongside each other. It's still not perfect (the only way you'll get perfect, as you've already discovered, is to have a real IE7 on its own real copy of XP), but it is much much closer to the real thing than IE's own 'compatiblity' mode.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't using IE9's IE7-compatibility-mode, I was using IE9's IE7-mode. Still, I know better now and will test in native installs from now on.

Comment: Running Virtual PC with different hard drive images containing each browser is another way to run IE 6, 7, 8 & 9 on the same machine.

Comment: Well, this doesn't solve the problem, but you do have the best answer in terms of preventing this from the get-go. Therefore, I award you my pitiful 50 rep bounty. :)

Comment: @Kerrick, this is at least twice now you've declared that your original question/problem is unsolved or unanswered.  What was it again?  Why your page looks different in IE 7 than in IE 9 running IE 7 Mode?  What kind of answer are you looking for?  Many people here are trying to tell you that those are really two different programs... each will have its own quirks.  As far as your other two problems... run your code through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org) and fix those issues for starters.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using the HTML5BoilerPlate ( http://html5boilerplate.com/ ) as a source of inspiration and guidance.  I am in the exact same situation:  Web Developer for a university and have to write a main site redesign.

I think you already did this, based on your source.  Are you using the latest version?  Perhaps there have been some updates to the HTML5BoilerPlate template that would address this.

I found a co-worker with the real IE7 installed and sure enough, your page looks bad.  I then checked out my mockup in the real IE7 and it looks OK (I consider my very lucky now).

My mockup is also based on the HTML5BoilerPlate template.

Another suggestion is to try commenting-out blocks of code and try to isolate the cause of the problem.

I think you slideshow is the cause of the problem (or at least the symptom).  I have had to re-implement my slideshow content using 3 different plugins.  Currently, I have settled on the jQuery cycle plugin for that kind of content: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

I really want to know the cause the of the problem, too.  The site looks great, by the way, when rendered the way it is supposed to look.  Good job!

---

Checkout this MSDN blog posting: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx

Comment: I started with the Boilerplate, and I think I've found that one of the largest problems is the slideshow just plain not working. The CSS I've applied to it won't work, the JS I'm using to manipulate it won't work (though I've excluded it for now).The floating bar also poses a problem, but it's only about 20px to the side so that's no big deal.

Answer (score 6):

The problem seems to be with the slideshow

Glancing through your [`script.js`](http://www.semo.edu/script.js) file i see this

```
/*
 * Here is the slideshow code.
 */

 // Screw ie7...
if ( !($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 7.0) ){
```

so i would start my search there, as it seems to ignore IE7 and below..

Comment: hehe. presumably slideshow is a third-party script? if its the way it sounds, I'd guess you're going to have to find an alternative script. (mind you, the author does make a good point in that comment!)

Comment: Actually, that's my slideshow. I put that comment and test in there to see if negating the slideshow would fix things. With or without the test/exclusion, it is still broken.

Comment: Besides, the slideshow's not the only problem. Look at the footer.

Also, the big question of why IE7 (running on XP) is acting differently than IE7 (running on IE9) hasn't even been touched.

Comment: @Kerrick- How can you say _"the big question of why IE7 (running on XP) is acting differently than IE7 (running on IE9) hasn't even been touched._"?  Several people have tried to explain that running IE9 in IE7 mode is NOT the same as running IE7... they are two different programs!  What exactly are you looking for here?

Answer (score 6):

Download the [free Microsoft Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) and MS's [free Hard Drive images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) containing IE 7, 8, etc... that's why they make these available.

There seems to be a million jQuery slideshow plugins and most are compatible with IE 7.

[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) is one and you can change it with CSS to look like what you have now.

[This page](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/07/42-jquery-image-gallery-plugins/) contains 42 various slide-show plugins.

---

**EDIT:**

I also recommend that the page be brought into [W3C compliance](http://validator.w3.org/) before tackling the other issues.

Comment: @Kerrick- It seems like you posted several unrelated questions within one.  To answer your original question as it's titled, _"Why does my page work in IE9's IE7 mode, but not in IE7 itself?"_; Does your page meet [compliance](http://validator.w3.org/) standards?  And like others have stated, running a browser emulation within a browser is **not** the same as running that browser natively.  In my posted answer, I'm suggesting a solution that allows you to run several versions of IE natively without having to use several different machines.

Comment: @Kerrick- As to your specific follow-up questions, "jQuery slideshow issue" and "why your footer is broken"... you may want to post those as two new questions.

Comment: @Kerrick- I ran your page through the W3C Validator and it has a few issues.  It would be worthwhile to take care of those compliance issues before tackling the specific bugs.

Comment: Just pay heed to **"Expires: This image will shutdown and become completely unusable on August 09, 2011."** and similar notes ;-)

Comment: That's true.  You will have to download new hard drive images every few months.

Answer (score 4):

May I recommend you avoid emulation approaches and test in actual IE7 on your machine by using [XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx).

Comment: Good point.  You should never assume anything, and test, test, test.  Emulators will almost never work exactly like the real thing.

Comment: Yeah, I've learned my lesson and shall be testing on an actual install from now on.

Answer (score 1):

First: always test on the actual browser. If we're talking about ie, use a virtual machine to test it. Never rely on "compatibility modes", "ies4linux", "ies4mac", "just use wine" and such. I've had a lot, but a LOT of headaches when not using virtual machines (you can use snapshots on your virtual machines - each snapshot is a browser version. This way you can have only one image but with multiple browsers).

Second: do this problem happens even if you remove that slideshow section from your script.js? Did you check if, after removing that section and reloading your page if it isn't a cached version of the old script.js? Sometimes a cached version is the source of all problems.

A little hack to fool your browser into not caching script.js is to add, when calling script.js from your markup, an arbitrary number (script.js?v=100 for example, and for each modification you do with your js, you modify this number. You can check SO's source, it uses a similar approach in some sections).

Third: try to do, before the "negation" in your script:

```
alert($.browser.msie);
alert($.browser.version);
alert($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 7.0);
```

...and see if ie alerts something or if it raises an exception. Sometimes ie will try to interpret your javascript, and raise an unknown exception for no reason whatsoever: if you don't catch it in a try/catch block everything will break from that point to the end of the script.

I know, it's a trial-and-error approach, but we have to isolate everything and try to understand exactly what's causing the error. If needed, repeat the third advice along the slideshow section.

Answer (score 0):

Alrgiht, this maybe the answer ur looking for. Go to F12 developer tools and click **IE9 browser mode** and **IE7 document mode** It will be IE7 standards, but a IE9 useragent. If that doesn't work, try using IE7 browser mode and document mode.

Answer (score -2):

I'm with the others in saying that the possible culprit is the slideshow. I would get a more CSS friendly slideshow:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html

And definitely test in the ACTUAL browser! You could use an online browser check site like browsershots.org. They take aLONG time to produce a shot of your site, but it is accurate.

Comment: I disagree.  jQuery Tools is very out of date, poorly supported and turns the _"write less, do more"_ jQuery tagline upside down.  And I've found the screenshots at browsershots.org to be lacking since you can't actually **use** your site.  Download the [free Microsoft Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) and MS's [free Hard Drive images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) containing IE 7, 8, etc... that's why they make these available.

Comment: I'd hardly use MS anything as a valuable tool. I find it less taxing and more reliable to use browsershots than the overhead of using a virtual pc. Do you think you can reproduce in the same amount of time all the browser shots from all the different builds of IE 7, 8 and 9 in those hard drive images? Browsershots does, and it also is free. I used jQuery Tools as an example; there are many others out there that may be better supported and work with IE better. I've used jQuery Tools with IE7 and IE8 and it works great. I'd like to know what everyone uses when they can't set up a virtual pc.

Comment: **Browser Shots is just a screen capture**... hardly comparable to actually using and testing the page.  I don't like MS either but if 50% of my visitors are still using Explorer then I have to test it.  VPC with an XP Hard Drive Image running IE 7 supplied by Microsoft is the **only** thing **exactly** the same as just using IE 7 in XP.

Comment: It's a screen capture of a virtual machine running an actual version of the browser. What you don't get out if it is actually going to source and seeing it as it is actually rendered in code. That part I don't like about browser emulation and snapshots. If you can't set up VPC, what's the next best thing, then?

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't setup VPC, the requirements are not that severe.  I'm running it on a 5 year old XP machine.  There are several "browsers" out there that claim to emulate any version of IE but they also introduce their own bugs and issues not seen in the actual Internet Explorer.  So if you can't actually run it on a particular version of Explorer, VPC or a real machine, then you effectively cannot test your site in that version of Explorer.  Stick to W3 standards, avoid the common IE bugs, and just hope it works.

Comment: Not being able to see rendered code in a snapshot should be the least of your worries.  What about not being able to hover, click, type, scroll, select, submit, tooltips, see animations, test modals, fill out forms, or interact with the page just like any real visitor would?