# Can I test in IE7 and assume that >IE7 will look the same?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I test my pages on IE7, Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

I've adopted the idea of adding a class to `html` in order to be able to write custom CSS tweaks absolutely, positively there is no other way to do it.  In other words, I don't abuse this facility.

I use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js ie-all lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js ie-all lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js ie-all lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
```

You'll notice that this is a modified version of the [HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) approach in that I am adding `ie-all`.  The reason for doing this is that, per the title, I am only testing on IE7.  Without something like an `ie-all` class I'd have to choose from one of the other classes for ie tweaks.  Other than testing on all versions of IE, who else would I handle this problem?

I do realize that `ie-all` is equivalent to `lt-ie9` at the moment.  I fully expect to see this code evolve to have a `lt-ie10` class which might change things.  Not sure what the best approach is here.

**EDIT:**

In re-reading my question I thought that most might think that the answer is self-evident: **Can't test on IE7 and have it work on newer versions of IE.**  I thought I should clarify with context.

I have been doing exactly that this for the last few years and have not run into any serious issues.  To be repetitive.  **I have been testing on IE7 and my code has worked without issues on newer versions of IE.**  It was only when I decided to "modernize" my boilerplate and look at other ideas that I realized that, in some cases, there are folks that must be writing custom CSS for each version of IE.

I have not seen the need to tweak for each version of IE. I have wasted countless hours fixing issues with IE7 that do not exist on Chrome, Safari and Firefox.  When I have done so it has always worked fine on other versions of IE.  Hence my modification to HTML5Boilerplate and the idea to add a single `ie-all` class to cover these special tweaks.

In addition to this, **I am now exploring fancier JQuery UI ideas** that, I thought, might not respond well to only testing on IE7.

Comment: *Never assume anything.* (Especially when it comes to IE - it tends to be unpredictable.)

Comment: Ain't that the truth.  Although I probably knew the answer I was secretly hoping that --for simple stuff-- there would be a case for all >ie7 MS browsers being OK with code tweaked for ie7.  Doesn't seem to be the case.  I guess it's time to spool-up a set of VM's and check, what, three more browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write standards-compliant code with a standards-inducing doctype and use progressive-enhancement, you will be just fine. These practices alone should ensure that your site will work very well in every version of IE today as well as in the last several years. The reason why people have *problems* with Internet Explorer today (generally speaking), is because they fail to do one (or more) of these things.

Keep in mind that Internet Explorer 10 dropped support for conditional-comments, so  try to ween yourself off of those, depending rather on careful coding and good practices.

To greatly reduce the burden of support all of the necessary software (and hardware in some cases) required for testing across various browsers, check out http://browserstack.com. You can quickly pick an OS, a Browser, and a Version and within seconds have a virtual machine up and running in your browser. You can even use this same service to *tunnel* into your local server/file-system to test local files.

Code well and wise, and IE won't be the pain that many think it to be.

Comment: Depends I suppose what you classify as "several years". IE7 was released in 2006 and has several significant bugs and shortcomings.

Comment: @steveax Every browser has several bugs and shortcomings. This doesn't change the fact that you're safest route is to use the safest practices; standards-compliant code, standards doctype, and progressive-enhancement.

Answer (score 2):

There have been massive changes in Internet Explorer since IE7, so you absolutely cannot test for 7 and assume that newer versions will work as well.  IE7 was released in 2006, and was very poor even by the standards of the time.

Unless you want to have classes for each version, I'd create one for <=IE8, and one for IE9 and above.

Answer (score 1):

<del>You could just write code that works in all browsers, like I do - never had a problem with it.</del>

You should ALWAYS test in different versions. Never assume it will work. I fell prey to this once when I assumed that Firefox wouldn't mess around with the contents of an `onClick` inline attribute, but it did (replaced it with "more correct" JavaScript and broke other code), the same goes for IE versions.

Your best bet is to use IE10. In its Developer Tools, you can test in all versions of IE from 7 upwards.

Comment: The IE7/8/9 modes in IE10 are not identical to the earlier browsers. Close, but there are [differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993222/why-does-my-page-work-in-ie9s-ie7-mode-but-not-in-ie7-itself). There is no substitute for testing in all the versions you need to support.

Comment: If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.  The link you provide is really valuable.

Comment: @martin's That would make this a Duplicate Question though ;)

Comment: Not sure that would be the case.  See the edit to my question.