# Custom CSS shows in IE10's IE7 emulator, but not in actual IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, sharepoint-2007

I'm at wit's end here and looking for help.  I have a SharePoint 2007 page that uses some home-made JavaScript CEWPs and custom CSS files.  When I open the page in IE10 and push it back to IE7 using the developer tools, the formatting looks similar to IE10.  But when I open the same page in actual IE7 on a virtual machine I've set up, the styling doesn't show.  I've been careful to use custom IDs and classes, and my rules are pointing to them, but I can't seem to budge the browser.  (It seems like a situation similar to the one described here: [Why does my page work in IE9's IE7 mode, but not in IE7 itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993222/why-does-my-page-work-in-ie9s-ie7-mode-but-not-in-ie7-itself))

What's really odd is that the background image I define in the custom CSS does show, but when I add any rules to that same area of the CSS file, no other rules seem to work.

I WILL say that the page appearance in actual IE7 is similar to when I view it in IE10's IE5 Quirks mode. Is the browser forcing the page into a quirks view? If so, how do I prevent that from happening?  The only master page modification I've made is to use the "x-ua-compatible" trick.

Here are the rules; they work fine in IE10 > IE7 but not in actual IE7:

```
.ms-quicklaunch {
    display:none;
}

.ms-navframe {
    display: none;
}

.tooltip {
    display: none;
}

.ms-bodyareaframe {
    background-image: url('/mypath/images/dkGrey.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3 table tbody tr td[vAlign] {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#allPriorities p:first-child {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#allPriorities #prioritiesWrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.priority .img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

#allPriorities #prioritiesWrapper .priority .title {
    margin: auto 0;
}

#allPriorities .priority {
width: 350px;
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px 30px;
padding: 15px;
background-color: black;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px solid white;
line-height: 2em;
border: 2px dashed #fff;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px black, 2px 1px 6px 4px rgba(10, 10, 0, 0.5);
}

#programs {
    width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 15px;
}

.program {
    padding: 0 10px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: left;
height: 200px;
margin: 20px 10px;
width: 30%;
overflow: auto;
border: 1px solid black;
color: black;
background-color: darkgray;
}

.program p {
    font-weight: bold;
padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
margin: 10px 0 5px;
}

.program  .programItem {
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.program .programItem .img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.program .linkItem {
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.program .programItem .title {
    margin: auto 0;
}
```

Comment: do you have doctype set?

Comment: I managed to get it working shortly after posting this last night.  I'm not entirely certain what caused the change, but I started by removing the "table tbody tr td[vAlign]" section from the rule above as well as the :first-child pseudo-selector.  I figured SharePoint would already have DOCTYPE set, and left all that alone within the master page.  Is that something I should do within the CEWP?

Comment: I have no idea what cewp is, i don't use sharepoint